# My front door’s handle is loose - is there anything I can do about it?

Tags: doors, lock

Here’s a video of it loose: https://imgur.com/a/XRWKlVn

Is there a way to fix it or do I need to replace the entire front door lock/handle?

Edit: added additional videos of the inside. Can I just buy the interior lever replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced the door latch with a new one and it worked like new. Easy $8 repair.

Answer (score 3):

Can't see from the video, typically that sort of sloppiness is from things you'll need to get the handle and trim off to tighten up. Or, in some cases the trim screws are loose holding the back to the front and you just need to tighten them.

So, in *most* cases, no replacement should be needed. But you *might* have an edge case where something's actually been broken, so replacement would be indicated. But I've seen plenty of doors that just needed some screws and the occasional nut tightened.

Open it up and post some pictures of what you find in your question.

Comment: I added some videos and photos of the inside (hard to record with one hand!). Everything inside is pretty loose.  https://imgur.com/a/XRWKlVn